# The button/input is not staying in the login background box/table

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the button/input is not staying in the login background box/table...
I tried everything but it just wont stay in ... and that login_bg should move and input have to stay in it while you are resizing the webbrowser

Here is mine CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-image:url('http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/6834/backgroundyq.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
/*  cursor: url('../css/images/cursor.cur'), auto;*/
 }

.login_bg {
    background-image: url('http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/6615/loginbgm.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
}

.login_info {
position: absolute;
margin: 350px 0 0 250px;
}

.login_input {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8451/inputy.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    left: 130px;
    height: 37px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And here's HTML code.

```
<div class="login_bg">
 <table class="login_info">
  <tr>
    <td height="32"><input type="text" name="account" id="account" class="login_input" tabindex="1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3TQMF/11/

Maybe i didnt asked well so if you want to know something what will help you to understand me more, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the title.. For future reference, please, don't use titles like "css is not cooperating".

Comment: You have position 'fixed' on the input. That won't move anywhere. A parent should be relative, children can then be absolute to move along with the parent.

Comment: Not using tables could help.

Comment: I agree with @N1xx1, I think you would be better off using divs and positioning elements inside of them. Without knowing what this is supposed to look like though, it's hard for us to help with the CSS. Do you have a mockup?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is more like the following (if I understand your focus is to keep the login bar centered). I ripped out some of the CSS and got rid of the table:

```
<body>
<div class="login_bg">
<input type="text" name="account" id="account" class="login_input" tabindex="1"/>
</div>
</body>
```

And:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {

  background-image:url('http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/6834/backgroundyq.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
/*  cursor: url('../css/images/cursor.cur'), auto;*/
 }

.login_bg {
    background-image: url('http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/6615/loginbgm.png');
    position: relative;
    width: 872px;
    height: 545px;
}

.login_input {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8451/inputy.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    left: 45%;
    top: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I need a table in login bar ... made from 2 sides ... left and right ... Into into the left one i want to add some Login/Password things and to the right side i wantt to add something like Patch List ... so this is not the solution :/

Comment: Just make another div like .login_input and move it to the right. You don't need to use a table.

Comment: for me it's better to use table :/

Comment: Okay I somehow found a way how to do it how i wanted... anyways thanks for every help :)